# Extending the Kivy ScrollView contents down

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I have a `FloatLayout` as a child of a `ScrollView` with `size_hint_y` set to `None`. I want to be able to extend it as I add more and more content. The problem is that since Kivy's coordinate system starts at the bottom-left, when I add to the `FloatLayout` height, all the content stays at the bottom. Can I somehow make it extend down? Because I don't think that moving all widgets up is efficient, especially if there's a lot of them and I need to handle the position of all children as well.
Here is a snippet that explains the problematic behaviour:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class TestApp(App):
    def extend_h(self, *args):
        global msg_float
        msg_float.height += 50

    def build(self):
        global msg_float
        msg_float = FloatLayout(size_hint_y = None)
        bt1_main = Button(on_press = self.extend_h)  
        bl = BoxLayout()
        sc = ScrollView()
        sc.add_widget(msg_float)
        bl.add_widget(sc)
        bl.add_widget(bt1_main)
        lb = Label(text = "Test",
                   size=(100,200),
                   size_hint = (None, None))
        msg_float.add_widget(lb)
        return bl

TestApp().run()
```

With a press of a button, the view extends and the `"Test"` label stays at the bottom, but I'd want it to stay on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [relative layout](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.relativelayout.html) instead of a float layout to fix the coords, but instead you should just omit using any of these, and add labels to a grid layout. Check examples at kivy repo:

https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/examples/widgets/scrollview.py

https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/examples/widgets/scrollview.kv